# Spring XML parsing within REST web service

Tags: java, xml, spring

I'm still investigating the options, but I would like to ask for suggestions.

I have a requirement where I need to build a RESTful web service, which would take an XML file, validate it against an XSD, and then store the data into Java objects (which would also eventually be put into an Oracle DB).

I'm leaning on using Spring MVC for the RESTful web service.  I've only worked through some simple examples to learn things, but I have a very basic RESTful WS working - able to do CRUD operations taking XML input.

What I'm not sure on, and still investigating, is how to validate the XML against an XSD in Spring?  And secondly, how to parse it in Spring, to put the XML data into Java objects.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!
Chris

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the webservice is up and running, you can use an helper class to validate your input XML string and another to unmarshal it using JAXB.

**Validation :**

```
public static boolean validator(String xml) {
    try {
        StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml);
        URL xsdResource = ValidarXML.class.getClassLoader().getResource("myPath/myXSD.xsd");
        SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
        Schema schema = factory.newSchema(xsdResource);
        Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
        validator.validate(new StreamSource(reader));
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
 }
```

**Unmarshalling**

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("foo.bar.MyClass");
Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
MyClass clazz = u.unmarshal(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xml)));
```